# How do I write tests for Cyclone in the style of Tornado?

Tags: python, unit-testing, migration, tornado, cyclone

I have been googling and asking on IRC to no avail. [Cyclone](http://cyclone.io/) is supposed to be a Tornado-like protocol for Twisted. But, there are no tests in the Cyclone repository and no-one has written up how to convert `tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase` tests to exercise code written against Cyclone.

1. How do I start a server to test the web interface?
2. Where is the `self.fetch()`?
3. Where is the documentation in Cyclone to describe how to convert an existing Tornado app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing like `tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase` in cyclone at the moment. Your best bet would be to use [Twisted Trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedTrial) to write unit tests. One (slightly kludgy) approach would be explicitly call `self.listener = reactor.listenTCP(<someport>, YourCycloneApplication())` in the `setUp` method inside your test case and call `self.listener.stopListening()` in the `tearDown` method.

Then, inside your test methods, you could use `cyclone.httpclient.fetch` to fetch the pages.
This is far from ideal. But as of now, this is the only way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what we are currently using to test our cylcone handler like we did with tornado:

```
from twisted.trial.unittest import TestCase
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from cyclone import httpclient

# copied from tornado
_next_port = 10000
def get_unused_port():
    """Returns a (hopefully) unused port number."""
global _next_port
    port = _next_port
    _next_port = _next_port + 1
    return port

class TxTestCase(TestCase):

    def get_http_port(self):
        """Returns the port used by the HTTPServer.

        A new port is chosen for each test.
        """
        if self.__port is None:
            self.__port = get_unused_port()
        return self.__port

    def setUp(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__port = None
        self._app = self.get_app()
        self._listener = None
        if self._app:
            self._listener = reactor.listenTCP(self.get_http_port(), self._app)
        return TestCase.setUp(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_app(self):
        return None

    def tearDown(self):
        if self._listener:
            self._listener.stopListening()

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def fetch(self, url, *args, **kwargs):
        response = yield httpclient.fetch('http://localhost:%s%s'%(self.get_http_port(), url), *args, **kwargs)
        defer.returnValue(response)
```

This way, you get the `fetch` method back ;)

And there are no more needs to use trial.

Here is an usage example:

```
from twisted.internet import defer

class Test(TxTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        return MyApplication()

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def some_test_method(self):
        res = yield self.fetch('/path/to/resource')
        self.assertEquals(200, res.code)
```

Hope that will help you.